# Lambda expression in a list comprehension Python

Tags: python, mongodb, lambda

So I have my pymongo cursor and very plain loop to get total sum. I need to fetch that value, also I am very new to Mongo and my approach might be not the best practice.

```
cursor = db.reportsColl.aggregate([
        {"$unwind": "$conditions"},
        {"$group": {"_id": "$_id", "sum": { "$sum": 1}}}])


x = 0
for result in cursor:
    x+= result['sum']
print(x)
```

I am trying to use lambda expression here, but I feel that I've kinda lost.

```
total = [(lambda x: x+result['sum'])(x) for _ in cursor]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you mean something like `total = sum(result['sum'] for result in cursor)`

Comment: @AChampion definitely! How I couldn't do it in the 1st place... Thanks.

Comment: @AliceJarmusch slightly confused as to what you're doing here... can't you modify your query and have mongo do it rather than post-processing in Python? Although, I'm not sure if you're trying to get the number of groups, or something else...

Comment: @JonClements if you can suggest how can I do it in mongo, I will be happy. Had never worked with it before, and I just need to grab some aggregated data for the further calculations.

Comment: @Alice that's what I'm wondering... perhaps the real question you should be asking is "How do I get the following using a mongo query" and describing what the aggregation you want is, your attempt (like above) and some sample data etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are building a list of incomplete sums, and that's a waste. Don't use a list comprehension for the side effects.

You don't even need to do this. Use the [`sum()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) with a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#generator-expressions) instead:

```
total = sum(result['sum'] for result in cursor)
```

Answer (score 0):

You only want to do is SUM.

So, you can try to do follow this:

```
In [9]: sum([1, 2, 3])
Out[9]: 6`
```

So, by this way, your code can be like:

```
total = sum([result['sum'] for result in cursor])
```

Comment: Drop the `[...]` brackets, there is no need to create a list first to sum the contents. Use a generator expression instead.